# What gender is the narrator of The Extinction Parade?

Tags: closure-limited, the-extinction-parade, max-brooks

While I was reading the short story *The Extinction Parade* by Max Brooks, in his anthology *Closure, Limited*, I imagined the narrator as a man.  I don't know why I assumed it was a man, but I did.  Last night I bought the graphic novels based on the story, and I was mildly surprised to see that the narrator is female.

I scanned through the print version of the story again, and I couldn't find anything that might indicate whether the narrator was male or female.  It really doesn't matter either way - I don't have a preference for male or female narrators, and it doesn't affect the story - but I'm still curious as to who assigned the narrator's gender:

- Did Brooks always intend for the character to be female, or did the people who made the graphic novels change it?
- Did Brooks even have a gender in mind while he was writing?

I would accept either a statement from Brooks, or some evidence that I failed to notice from the original print version of the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Did Brooks always intend for the character to be female, or did the people who made the graphic novels change it?**

Max Brooks *is* the person who made the graphic novels — comic book series, really.  He wrote the short story, which is one of four in *Closure, Limited*, and then commissioned and wrote the ensuing comic books, in close cooperation with Avatar Press publisher William Christensen.

[image]

In fact, Brooks chose Avatar Press to publish the comics *because* they promote artistic freedom and didn't force him to change his vision:

> **INTERVIEWER:** What was it about Avatar Press that made this the perfect home for a series like ‘Extinction Parade’?
>
> **MAX BROOKS:** The thing about Avatar is that they give you artistic freedom, and let me tell you that artistic freedom is becoming an endangered species. More and more it’s becoming about comic books being developed for film, so you have to write it like a movie. Most publishers are just about making a buck, and William Christensen is really about letting artists run free.

([Source](http://bloody-disgusting.com/news/3251202/exclsuive-interview-world-war-z-author-max-brooks-discusses-the-zombie-vs-vampire-war-in-the-pages-of-the-extinction-parade/))

From this, I would conclude that it was Brooks' decision to have a female narrator in the comics rather than the decision of anyone else.

**Did Brooks even have a gender in mind while he was writing?**

Brooks doesn't seem to have publicly commented on the gender of the narrator of the original short story, and whether he chose the gender before, during, or after writing the story.  Furthermore, he hasn't stated how planning the comic books may have affected the gender of the narrator.

Comment: Excellent answer as always.

Comment: @WadCheber : Thanks --- good questions tend to engender good answers. (No pun intended.)

Comment: It actually hadn't occurred to me that Brooks might have been closely involved in writing the comics.  I don't know why I was so dense.  Maybe because he had so little involvement in the movie adaptation of *World War Z*?  Maybe because he is a valuable commodity now, which wasn't the case when he published WWZ?  Maybe it was just a failure of imagination on my part.  That's probably it.

Comment: @WadCheber : No worries.  With so many franchises having so many licensed adaptations and spin-offs these days, it's actually reasonable not to assume anything, a priori, about his involvement.

Comment: Indeed.  Plus, his father is Mel Brooks, so he probably has ridiculous amounts of money to spend on having people write adaptations for him.  Sometimes I feel like he has no business being so talented and awesome, considering the fact that his dad is Mel Brooks and his mom is Anne Bancroft.  How many famous and talented people does a single family need?